# click_no_wait does not work the second time when autoIt is used to handle the file download box

Tags: ruby, watir, autoit

I am facing the problem where I call the method click_no_wait on a 
control which displays a "File Download" box. It works fine for the 
1st time. i use Auto It to handle the file download box and save the 
file at a particular location. Now, when I try to use the 
click_no_wait on the same control, it won't display the File Download 
box, but If i refresh the browser before calling the click_no_wait, it 
will display the File Download box. So, my question is that is it the 
case that Auto It is not being released and thus click_no_wait cannot 
find the control or is there something wrong with the implementation 
of the click_no_wait method.

Environment: 
OS: Microsoft XP SP2 
Ruby : ruby 1.8.6 patchelevel 398 
Watir : 1.8.1

Following is the way I am using the control

```
def click_export_button 
  control = browser.button(:id,'export-button') 
  $DEBUG = true 
  #browser.refresh         #- If this line is not commented, the dialog appears 
  control.click_no_wait    #-- I replace click_no_wait with click and/or click! and the code freezes, so the control is found 
  download_file("C:\\test.csv") 
  $DEBUG = false 
end
```

Here's the code for downloading the file

```
def download_file(filePath = nil) 
  autoIt = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control") 
  timeout = 10 
  fileDownloadWindowTitle = "File Download" 
  handle = autoIt.WinWait(fileDownloadWindowTitle, "Do you want to open or save this file?", timeout) 
  retVal = nil 
  unless (handle.eql? @autoItError) 
    autoIt.WinActivate(fileDownloadWindowTitle) 
    autoIt.ControlClick(fileDownloadWindowTitle, "", "&Save") 
    saveWindowTitle = "Save As" 
    windowHandle = autoIt.WinWaitActive(saveWindowTitle, "", timeout) 
    if (windowHandle == 1) 
      retVal = save_file(saveWindowTitle, autoIt, filePath) #-- function to save the file to the location 
    end 
  else 
    puts "Unable to download the file" 
  end 
  autoIt.ole_free 
  return retVal 
end
```

Here's the error which I am getting

```
ruby -e "$:.unshift('c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/ 
watir/win32ole').unshift('c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ 
commonwatir-1.8.1/lib').unshift('c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ 
firewatir-1.8.1/lib').unshift('c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ 
watir-1.8.1/lib');require 'c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/ 
lib/watir/core';Watir::Button.new(Watir::IE.attach(:hwnd, 
6751822), :unique_number, 3).click!();" 
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/watir/element.rb:58:in 
`assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using :unique_number, 3 
(Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException) 
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/watir/ 
element.rb:275:in `click!' 
        from -e:1
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure enough about this to offer it as an answer, but I think there's been some work on click_no_wait in more recent versions of Watir.. You might want to try updating to a newer Watir version and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Looks like it could potentially be a problem with clicking the download button itself, rather than AutoIt.

Is something altering the html on your page between the first and second attempts to download a file?

Might explain why it's solved by a refresh.  The ID on the button is definitely the same pre and post click, yeah?

Comment: Yes, but some elements are updated by AJAX, like a div being hidden or made visible. Does that have an issue with click_no_wait not able to see the control

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  If it works anything like Watir-Webdriver, if you store elements in variables for later use, they will become invalid if the html on the page changes significantly.  As your method for clicking the button defines the element within it each time (control = browser.button(:id,'export-button') ) I can't see this being the problem, really.  But just in case, try changing your code so it always references the button being clicked by the watir code directly, rather than in a variable (i.e. always browser.button(:id,'export-button').click_no_wait

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it still didn't work. Well assuming the suggestion you made, it still doesn't make any sense that the click method finds it, but the click_no_wait cannot find it. I think there might be something wrong in the click_no_wait functionality since I also put in a sleep before calling the click_no_wait

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add following before your click_no_wait:

```
"browser.refresh"
```